# Help with corrupted NTFS partition

Tags: partitioning, ntfs, fsck, testdisk

My Ubuntu isn't able to mount a partition.

It suddenly became unreadable because of a corrupt Master File Table. `chkdsk /f` is unable to correct it, saying:

```
Windows will now check the disk.
Corrupt master file table.
Windows will attempt to recover master file table from disk.
Windows cannot recover master file table.  CHKDSK aborted
```

I tried with `ntfsfix` without success:

```
ntfsfix /dev/sda5

Mounting volume... ntfs_mapping_pairs_decompress() failed: Input/output error
Failed to load $MFT: Input/output error
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... ntfs_mapping_pairs_decompress() failed: Input/output error
Failed to load $MFT: Input/output error
FAILED
Failed to startup volume: Input/output error
Checking for self-located MFT segment... OK
ntfs_mapping_pairs_decompress() failed: Input/output error
Failed to load $MFT: Input/output error
Volume is corrupt. You should run chkdsk.
```

I tried [the following instructions](http://tecnovortex.com/como-recuperar-una-particion-ntfs-ilegible/), but `ntfsclone` said that there were an I/O error

```
ntfsclone -o /media/backup/partition.ntfs --rescue --ignore-fs-check --force /dev/sda5
```

ntfsclone v2013.1.13AR.1 (libntfs-3g)
ntfs_mapping_pairs_decompress() failed: Input/output error
Failed to load $MFT: Input/output error
ERROR(5): Opening '/dev/sda5' as NTFS failed: Input/output error

I did a successful clone with dd, so I'm not very sure if it is caused by an I/O error.

```
dd if=/dev/sda5 of=/media/backup/partition.dd bs=32M
```

After copying it, I tried again to use ntfsclone from the copied file.
I had the same response, so I think that the disk is Ok (no I/O error), but the master file table is corrupted.

What should I do at this point?

Comment: You have a dual boot system, Right?

Comment: Yes.  Windows Vista and Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Maybe the SMART values of that drive give you an idea? You could also try to run `testdisk` on the image for data recovery in case you need them.

Comment: Run `testdisk` and rewrite the partition table.

Answer (score 3):

## Try Testdisk.

Testdisk can use the backup boot sector to fix a corrupted NTFS boot sector.

The primary boot sector is sector zero of the filesystem and the backup NTFS boot sector is located near the end of the filesystem.

Even if the boot sector is accidentally overwritten, the backup should be intact.

Testdisk checks the boot sector and the backup boot sector. If the boot sector and backup boot sector mismatch, you can restore the NTFS boot sector from its backup or;  update the backup NTFS boot sector with the current boot sector.

To install it:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
sudo -i
apt-get update
apt-get install testdisk
```

If Microsoft's Checkdisk failed to repair the MFT:

Run TestDisk ---- In the `Advanced menu` ---- Select `your NTFS partition` ---- `Choose Boot` ---- Then `Repair MFT`.

TestDisk will compare the MFT and MFT mirror. If the MFT is damaged, it will try to repair the MFT using the backup. If the MFT backup is damaged, it will use the main MFT.

[**Main Page**](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/)

[**Source**](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/Advanced_NTFS_Boot_and_MFT_Repair)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tryed it, but the problem remains.  I also tried with rebuild bs. Finally ended using a recovery tool for windows for my own code and docs

Comment: have the same issue. please tell which recovery tool did you use?